# How to add an increment field to Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to create an google form with one incremental id and display that id to the user on submission of the google form i have searched a bit about it but i didn't get an answer on this as per my needs. if any one knows any work around to this please let me know. i don't have much idea about google forms

i have searched about it and found out it might be possible using google form add-ons

I just want an simple form with 4-5 fields and one incremental id and want to display that id to user on submission of the form

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything like this. Because

- No ways to edit the current response
- We can't set a default value for Form's fields

You can surrogate of this

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} FormSubmit
 * @property {GoogleAppsScript.Forms.Form} source
 */

/**
 *
 * @param {FormSubmit} e
 */
function onsubmit(e) {
  var form = e.source;
  var c = form.getItems()[0].asListItem();
  c.setChoiceValues([+c.getChoices()[0].getValue() + 1]);
}
```

See the video example https://www.facebook.com/oshliaer/videos/2438414829578425/

Answer (score 0):

### You need to incorporate content that is dynamically pulled from a spreadsheet

**Workflow of a possible solution:**

- Bind your form to a destination spreadsheet (if not already done)
- Bind a script to to form
- Withdraw e.g. the row of the last form response
- Use this value (or modify it as desired) as an incremental Id
- Incorporate this incremental ID into the title or description of the form
- Bind a [installable onFormSubmit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to your main function

**Sample:**

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID OF YOUR DESTINATION SPREADSHEET').getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var id=lastRow-1;
  FormApp.getActiveForm().setDescription('ID '+id);
}
```

Keep in mind that the change will need some seconds to propagate, the ID might not update directly if the form is submitted with a higher frequency